# Facebook iframe size changed

Tags: facebook

Did Facebook just change their iframe size or implement some other breaking change?

I have Facebook app that now appears below the ads on the page because the iframe width seems to have changed. It looks like the ads have an added margin or padding on them.

I have testing in IE9 and Chrome both with the exact same results.

Is anyone else having this problem, have they made a change or is it a temporary bug?

Comment: It seems a general problem

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9304147/facebook-page-tab-iframe-appears-on-bottom/9304256#9304256

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer below is from my post on a similar question: [Facebook page tab iframe appears on bottom](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9304147/facebook-page-tab-iframe-appears-on-bottom)

---

It is in fact a bug. I've just spent an hour looking into it.

It appears that they have increased the width of the right pane and it has caused the content area to shrink to less than 520px.

Unfortunately, the iframe that Facebook uses to display app content is hardcoded with a 520px width and you are unable to modify it. Need to wait till Facebook pushes out an update.

Edit: Bug reported to facebook already. Details [here](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/298512163544012?browse=search_4f3c5c801a70d4639459595)

Comment: Quickest answer in the west!  Wow, 2 minutes to read and reply.  +1 for Andy.